# cannot access s3 bucket using vertica

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, vertica

I am running vertica-ce in docker and I created a table , now i wanna export that table as parquet to s3 bucket, when i tried to export using `EXPORT TO PARQUET(directory = 's3://s3-bucket-name/data')` I got error `ERROR 8198:  Unable to verify if directory [s3://Bucket-name/data/] exists due to 'Access Denied'` I know why im getting this error because i need to give the `access_key,secret_key` but im unable to use `awslib` inside my docker container so i tried `docker exec -it vertica-ce bash -l` and accessed my container and tried to install the `awscli` but `apt-get,yum,apk`, nothing is working.

[image: this the error screenshot i got:]

if any one have solution for this please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. **Set AWS parameters in the session.**

   There are a bunch of S3 settings that you can set. For instance, if you need to set is the access and secret key, you can do this:

   ```
   => ALTER SESSION SET AWSAuth='access_key:secret_key';
   => EXPORT TO PARQUET(directory = 's3://s3-bucket-name/data');
   ```

   Depending on your setup, you may need to set additional config options (e.g. region, endpoint url, etc). All of the settings are documented here: https://www.vertica.com/docs/12.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/S3Parameters.htm
2. **Create a new version of the image that has aws cli in it.**

   docker-ce is currently a CentOS based OS, so it uses the yum package manager. You can create a new image using the sample `Dockerfile`:

   ```
   FROM vertica/vertica-ce:latest

   USER root
   RUN set -x \
     && yum -q -y makecache \
     && yum install -y unzip \
     && yum clean all \
     && rm -rf /var/cache/yum \
     && cd /tmp \
     && curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o awscli.zip \
     && unzip awscli.zip \
     && /tmp/aws/install -i /usr/bin/aws-cli -b /usr/bin
   USER dbadmin
   ```
3. **Mount a volume so that you can access it from your host PC.**

   With this approach you can use the aws cli that you have installed locally to copy them to an s3 bucket.

   Run this docker command to start the ce container persisting everything in `/data` to a local `vertica-data` directory.

   ```
   docker run -p 5433:5433 \
              --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/vertica-data,target=/data \
              --name vertica_ce \
              vertica/vertica-ce:latest
   ```

   Run `EXPORT TO PARQUET` using the in-container path `/data`.

   Access the parquet files from your PC in the `vertica-data` directory.

Comment: I have tried this, yum is running but still i couldn’t get access to s3 bucket im getting access denied

Comment: and i want to export the parquet file to s3 bucket not to my local system

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I added another option that you can try, which hopefully is what you are trying to do.